# Ajax not moving my Uploaded File to where it needs to be

Tags: php, ajax

The concept is pretty simple, I need to upload a file without refreshing the page, so I'm using an ajax. I've never done an upload ajax before, so I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

```
function uploadAttachment(){
    var name = document.getElementById("file").files[0].name;
    var did = <? echo $did ?>;
    var form_data = new FormData();
    var oFReader = new FileReader();
    oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("file").files[0]);
    var f = document.getElementById("file").files[0];
    var fsize = f.size||f.fileSize;
    if(fsize > 2000000)
    {
        alert("File Size is too large. Please make sure your file's size is less than 2MB.");
    }
    else
    {
        form_data.append("file", document.getElementById('file').files[0]);
        $.ajax
        ({
            url:"/assets/ajax/disciplinaries_upload.php?did="+did,
            method:"POST",
            data: form_data,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            beforeSend:function()
            {
                $('#uploaded_file').html("<label class='text-success'>File Uploading...</label>");
            },   
            success:function(data)
            {
                $('#uploaded_file').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

And my disciplinaries_upload.php ajax as follows;

```
<?php
$did = $_GET['did'];

if($_FILES["file"]["name"] != '')
{
     $test = explode('.', $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
     $fname = reset($test);;
     $ext = end($test);
     $name = $fname . '_' .$did. '.' . $ext;
     $location = '/assets/uploads/files/disciplinary_attachments/' . $name;  
     move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $location);
     if (file_exists($location)) {
        echo '<label class="text-success">File Uploaded Successfully</label>';
    } else {
        echo '<label style="color: red">File Upload Failed</label><br> Original File Name: '.$_FILES["file"]["name"].'<br> Extension: '.$ext.'<br> Newly Generated Name: '.$name.'<br>File Location: '.$location;
    }
}
?>
```

The problem seems to be that it's not actually uploading the file. I'm receiving the upload failed error that I've created which looks as follows;

```
File Upload Failed
Original File Name: test.txt
Extension: txt
Newly Generated Name: test_25.txt
File Location: /assets/uploads/files/disciplinary_attachments/test_25.txt
```

So by the looks of it, it does actually receive the file and knows where it needs to go... it just doesn't actually upload it there.

Comment: Have you checked the server's error logs?

Comment: When you say server's error logs, you mean through the inspect console? If so, I see none.

Comment: The server has a set of error logs that you should be able to inspect. If not, add the following to the top of your PHP scripts `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Alright, after adding that I'm receiving this now: Warning: move_uploaded_file(/assets/uploads/files/disciplinary_attachments/test_25.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/www/users/keepnxcanc/assets/ajax/disciplinaries_upload.php on line 13 Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/usr/home/keepnxcanc/.tmp/phpwL6Uhj' to '/assets/uploads/files/disciplinary_attachments/test_25.txt' in /usr/www/users/keepnxcanc/assets/ajax/disciplinaries_upload.php on line 13

Comment: That same information would be reflected in the error logs, so you should find them. Check the permissions on the folder to make sure you can write to it.

Comment: Try to change your `$location = '/assets/uploads/files/disciplinary_attachments/' . $name;` to the full path: `$location = '/usr/www/users/keepnxcanc/assets/uploads/files/disciplinary_attachments/' . $name;`. `/assets` probably doesn't exist on your filesystem (alongside `/usr`, `/var`, `/mnt` etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to both @Jay Blanchard and @kerbholz the code now works. All I had to do was change

```
 $location = '/assets/uploads/files/disciplinary_attachments/' . $name;
```

to

```
 $location = '/usr/www/users/keepnxcanc/assets/uploads/files/disciplinary_attachments/' . $name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this issue might happen because of *Upload file size limitation* and type or *Destination write permeation* or *Destination path is not satisfying* or *file upload over http/https* is blocked by security team.

**Solution:**

**Upload file size limitation:** By default web servers might allow to upload up to 1MB. you need to change the property called `Max_upload_size` to you requirement.

**Destination write permeation:** Some times we might forgot to remove wright protection to upload destination folder. So, Change the permissions to disable wright protection of the destination folder.

**Destination path is not satisfying:** Some times the destination path might not clear to make changes in. So, better to provide complete path.
code snip1: place at the top of you logic in *index.php*

```
define("BASE_PATH", __DIR__);
```

code snip2: change this `$location` in *disciplinaries_upload.php*

```
$location = BASE_PATH . '/assets/uploads/files/disciplinary_attachments/' . $name;
```

**File upload over http/https:** if your security team is enabling any restrictions, as them to enable. or make your self whitelist.

**finally:** a slight change in your code.

Code snip:

```
<?php
//comment this two lines in production
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

//define("BASE_PATH", __DIR__); //if both index.php and disciplinaries_upload.php in same location, comment this else keep it in index.php 
$did = $_GET['did'];
if(count($_FILES) > 0)
{
     $test = explode('.', $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
     $fname = reset($test);;
     $ext = end($test);
     $name = $fname . '_' .$did. '.' . $ext;
     $location = BASE_PATH . '/assets/uploads/files/disciplinary_attachments';
     $permition_cod = substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms($location)), -4);
     @chmod($location, "0777");
     if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $location.'/'.$name)) {
        echo '<label class="text-success">File Uploaded Successfully</label>';
    } else {
        echo '<label style="color: red">File Upload Failed</label><br> Original File Name: '.$_FILES["file"]["name"].'<br> Extension: '.$ext.'<br> Newly Generated Name: '.$name.'<br>File Location: '.$location;
    }
    @chmod($location, $permition_cod);
}
?>
```

Good luck...